# How can I define preprocessor flags in iOS project and use it in Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**My Problem**: I defined the preprocessor flag for my Xcode project, but it doesn't work as I used it in my Swift code.

**What I've Done**: I defined multiple Targets for my Xcode project (and multiple schemes as well) and for each target created a custom build configuration file (`.xcconfig` file). For each Target, I override `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` flag in my `.xcconfig` file.

My `ca805.debug.xcconfig` file is like this:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Common-ca805/Pods-Common-ca805.debug.xcconfig"
#include "base.debug.xcconfig"

// other configs

SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = CA805
```

And I assigned each build configuration to each Target in `.xcodeproj` file.

In Swift code I used this flag like below:

```swift
#if CA805
print("I'm using CA805 target specific code")
#else
print("I'm using common code")
#endif
```

And it printed `I'm using common code`.

Also, I've tried to add `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` flag using `Podfile` but it didn't work:

```rb
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!

abstract_target 'Common' do
  project 'Main', 'base.debug' => :debug, 'base.release' => :release
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for all targets
  # ...

  # Define Targets
  target 'Main'
  target 'ca805'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name.start_with?('Pods-Common')
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if !config.name.start_with?('base')
          target_name = target.name.split('-')[2].upcase
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', "#{target_name}=1"]
          config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', "-D#{target_name}"]
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', "#{target_name}"]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I checked `Active Compilation Conditions` section in my Target's `Build Settings` tab and something overrides my flag and I don't know the reason.

[Active Compilation Conditions section in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVnjw.png)

Comment: Maybe using user defined settings instead of compilation conditions?

Comment: @Cristik I used `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in `ca805.debug.xcconfig` file as well, but it didn't work. Also, I used that in `Podfile` as you see but it didn't work too.
If you think of another way can you describe it?
The only way that flag worked was when I defined it manually in `xcodeproj` file in my Target from Xcode editor (`Build Settings` tab).
But I want to add preprocessors automatically using `.xcconfig` file or `Podfile`. I think this way is more scalable and other developers are able to define new Targets easier, If they define configs manually it's error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround for this issue. I modified `.xcconfig` files:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name.start_with?('Pods-Common')
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if !config.name.start_with?('base')
          target_name = target.name.split('-')[2]
          flag = target_name.upcase
          puts "[Injecting flag:'#{flag}' to '#{target_name}.#{config.name.downcase}.xcconfig'"
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          # read from xcconfig to build_settings dictionary
          build_settings = Hash[*File.read(xcconfig_path).lines.map{|x| x.split(/\s*=\s*/, 2)}.flatten]
          # modify FLAGS
          build_settings['SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS'] = "$(inherited) #{flag}"
          # write build_settings dictionary to xcconfig
          File.open(xcconfig_path, 'w') {|file| file.puts ''}
          build_settings.each do |key, value|
            File.open(xcconfig_path, 'a') {|file| file.puts "#{key} = #{value}"}
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```